# How can I do Z in Z transform?

Tags: fonts, equations, matrices

How can I write this formula? Thank you for helping.

[image]

Comment: That's an ordinary italic (Times) lowercase "z".  The tail is a design detail, and it's usually designed differently for math because it causes problems when applying subscripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I find far more eye-catching than the "swashy" `z` while in math mode is the huge amount of whitespace involving many (but not all) terms of the form `( ... )`. To accomplish this separation, I define a macro called `\myparens` in the following example, which may be compiled under pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX.

Here's the output from running the code under LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\else % either Lua(La)TeX of Xe(La)TeX are in use
   \usepackage{unicode-math}
   \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
   \setmathfont{XITS Math}
\fi
\newcommand\myparens[1]{(\mkern5mu#1\mkern5mu)}
\begin{document}

\[
Y\myparens{z} = H\myparens{z}x\myparens{z}
=\bigl( H\myparens{1} + h\myparens{2}z^{-1}+\cdots+h\myparens{n+1}z^{-n}\bigr) x\myparens{z}
\]

\iftutex
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[StylisticSet=2]
\[
Y\myparens{z} = H\myparens{z}x\myparens{z}
=\bigl( H\myparens{1} + h\myparens{2}z^{-1}+\cdots+h\myparens{n+1}z^{-n}\bigr) x\myparens{z}
\]
\fi

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, to address the OP's follow-up questions and comments.

> How can I get the second equal to the bottom line?

I'm assuming that you want to introduce a line break right before the second `=` symbol and place that symbol immediatel below the first one. If this assumption is correct, I suggest you load the `amsmath` package and use its `split` environment, as follows.

```
\[
\begin{split}
Y\myparens{z} 
&= H\myparens{z}x\myparens{z} \\
&=\bigl( H\myparens{1} + h\myparens{2}z^{-1}
  +\cdots+h\myparens{n+1}z^{-n}\bigr) x\myparens{z}
\end{split}
\]
```

You also wrote,

> I also don't want to add so many usepackages. Can it be written in a simpler way?

I would disagree with the assessement that my sample answer loads a lot of LaTeX packages. If you're sure that you'll ever use pdfLaTeX to compile your document, the preamble code can be simplified to

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % for Times Roman clone, with "swash-y" `z`. 
\newcommand\myparens[1]{(\mkern5mu#1\mkern5mu)}
```

Here's the output of putting both elements together:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' environment
   \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % for Times Roman clone
   \newcommand\myparens[1]{(\mkern5mu#1\mkern5mu)}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
Y\myparens{z} 
&= H\myparens{z}x\myparens{z} \\
&=\bigl( H\myparens{1} + h\myparens{2}z^{-1}
  +\cdots+h\myparens{n+1}z^{-n} \bigr) 
  x\myparens{z}
\end{split}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I get the second equal to the bottom line?I also don't want to add so many usepackages. Can it be written in a simpler way?

Comment: @ZangLi - I've posted an addendum to address the poins in your follow-up comment.